# Adding firebase_auth package, Android simulation - app won't start

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

my goal is to get the example app "working" (counter) with this import line included:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

I am using VS Code.

- I verify the app loads fine w/o this line
- I add this line (yes, I am not using it)
- I add    firebase_auth: '^0.8.0+1'  to dependencies in pubspace.yaml
- I add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' to the bottom of android/app/build.gradle
- I add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' w/in dependencies in file android/build.gradle

I debug.  Build works, no errors.  App does not come up on simulator.  My "biggest" frustration is I am not given any feedback on what I did wrong.

Q: how do we debug these type of challenges with no feedback?

Q: the reason I stripped flutter <-> firebase to this simple example is because when I went through the examples, I couldn't get the app to load when I added firebase.

Is it completely obvious what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There's no error? Try then building the debug apk manually via the console and see what happens.

Comment: As you were so detailed in the steps, I have to ask: did you create the project in the firebase console? did you follow the steps there as well and updated all your info (project, etc)?

Comment: Hi George and Feu, I very much appreciate your help.  I got it to work.  I was doing incredibly dumb things like in VS code looking at the PROBLEMS  versus DEBUG CONSOLE.  Then, I was having challenges with the latest firebase_auth 0.8.0+1 ... I shut everything down and rechecked firebase configuration.  I now got it to work on both Android and iOS simulators.